# custom validation does not seem to get registered

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Inside a tab, I have a form that is dynamically loaded via ajax. Since the name of the field is dynamic too(e.g. `<input name='title1' id='title1', class='tRequired'>`), I write a custom validation method inside the "on complete" like this. However, the custom code does not get executed (the alert never pops up) no matter what i try.

```
$.ajax
                (   
                    {   
                        url: 'index.php?func=trainingmgr&aAction=displayAddForm', <br>
                        type: 'GET',<br>
                        dataType: 'html',<br>
                        complete: function(req, err) 
                            {   
                                //Append response to the tab's body <br>
                                $(href, '#trainingTabs').append(req.responseText);

                                $.validator.addMethod
                                (   
                                    'tRequired', 
                                    function(value, element) 
                                    {   
                                        if(value == '')
                                        { 
                                          alert('I am empty'); <====== Never pops up
                                          return true; 
                                        }
                                        else return false;
                                    },  
                                    '<br>Required field'
                                );  

                                $('#upload' + index).click
                                (   
                                    function() 
                                    { $('#addForm' + index).validate(); }
                                );  
                            }   
                    }   
                );
```

Comment: What validator plugin are you using?

Comment: first of all, can you confirm that the ajax complete function is executed?  besides the addmethod to the validator, does the rest of the complete function works?
if so, it might be that your custom added method does not necessarily work on a default '.validate()' call without options.
you will have to specify a rules option, with tRequired: true; for the fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
value == null
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Jeremy's answer,

Try

```
value === ''
```